# What are/were the Customs requirements for astronauts?

Tags: history, astronaut-lifestyle, travel

When the Apollo 11 astronauts returned to US territory they famously went through US Customs where they listed "moon" as part of their flight routing:

[image: Apollo 11 customs declaration]

Was that a one-off?

What are procedures today? For places that require passport exit controls such as Europe and Russia do astronauts have to go through passport control before launch, too?

Answer (score 8):

Before launch, NASA (or whatever space agency a particular astronaut is affiliated with) keep their passports and visa, and bring it back to them when they land. Since the astronauts land in Kazakhstan, they need their official documents so they can leave the country and go back home.

This is Canadian astronaut Chris Hadfield's reply to the question regarding customs.

> NASA kept our passports and visas, and brought them to us at landing, so we had them at the Karaganda airport to leave Kazakhstan.

So the answer to your question: Yes, astronauts  do need to go through customs before launch, and upon landing.

[Source](https://www.theatlantic.com/technology/archive/2013/12/how-do-we-welcome-astronauts-back-to-earth-by-making-them-go-through-customs/282122/).

Comment: That's to *leave* Kazakhstan, which is understandable. What about *entering* Kazakhstan? What about leaving Russia in the first place? (AFAIK while physically in Kazakhstan, Baikonur is part of Russia for visa purposes)

Comment: Yes they need to go through customs to enter Kazakhstan, but then NASA keeps their official documents.

Comment: The Apollo crews didn't land in Russia. Why did they go through customs?

Comment: @OrganicMarble: I think the document shown in the question was a joke.

Comment: @OrganicMarble the Apollo crew landed in international waters. It depends on when an arriving ship is/is not required to go through customs (arriving from overseas: yes; cruise without visiting foreign ports: probably not; picking up strays while underway: maybe).

Comment: @Hobbes - do US Naval vessels have to clear customs on arrival in the US? I have no idea one way or the other...

Comment: According to [this Quora answer](https://www.quora.com/Are-US-Navy-sailors-and-ships-subject-to-immigration-clearance-and-customs-inspection-upon-returning-to-US-territory-from-overseas-deployment-It-appears-that-such-is-the-case-with-Royal-New-Zealand-Navy-sailors-and), US Navy sailors **do** go through customs to return to the US.